# What am I missing? TypeError: load_dataset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name' .... in name is it the file name, the file path?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter

TypeError: load_dataset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name' .... in name is it the file name, the file path??

Jupyter notebooks, `us_names_by_decade_df = sns.load_dataset()`.    the previous file I used simply had it's file name in there and worked.

[image]

Comment: What dataset are you trying to load? And how would `sns.load_dataset` know what dataset to load? See [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.load_dataset.html).

Comment: I tried the name.csv for dataset but it didn't work...I can view with this. us_names_by_decade_df = pd.read_csv("desktop/data/us_names_by_decade.csv") - this is new for me so am trying to understand how the last line shows me what's in the file but I can't  use the same principle to load dataset

Comment: According to the documentation I linked above, `name` is the "name of the dataset (`{name}.csv` on https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data)", so it's for loading "built-in" datasets provided by Seaborn, _not_ one's own datasets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear. If you want to load your custom dataset, use `pandas.read_csv('name.csv')`. If you want to load the already available dataset of seaborn, first of all use `seaborn.get_dataset_names()` to get the list of dataset names.
Then pass the dataset name in `seaborn.load_dataset()`

See here https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.load_dataset.html

`name` is the name of the dataset available in seaborn, not your custom dataset name.